# What setting(s) cause neovim's inconsistent formatting in typescript enums?

Tags: typescript, vim

When I type out a typescript enum in vim, the first item gets two spaces of indent. The other items get four spaces. Example:

```
export enum Formatme {
  One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
}
```

I want two space indents for all items.

I have a bunch of plugins and formatting related settings. When I disable plugin typescript-vim (https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim) I lose automatic indenting in typescript files altogether.

I have the following related settings:

```
noautoindent
nosmartindent
nocindent
cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
indentkeys=o,O,*<Return>,<>>,<<>,/,{,},0],0)
```

Can anyone tell me what setting I should be looking for in order to get a consistent 2 space indent for all items?

Comment: How about `indentexpr?`

Comment: @filbranden `indentexpr=GetTypescriptIndent()`. This appears to have been set up by `typescript-vim`: https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/search?q=gettypescriptindent&unscoped_q=gettypescriptindent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug of vim-typescript.

See [Issue #133](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/issues/133), which is about "Wrong indentat with interfaces", but the first comment talks about enums and uses an example very close to yours.

The author of the plug-in acknowledges the issue, but says this plug-in is not their priority at the moment, so they're unlikely to fix it themselves. (They're open to receiving pull requests with fixes though.)

Note that the README file also [points that out](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/blob/master/README.md#indenting):

> This plugin includes a custom indenter (based on pangloss/vim-javascript's indenter), it works pretty well but there are cases where it fails. If these bother you or want to use other indent settings you can disable it by setting a flag in your .vimrc:
>
> ```
> let g:typescript_indent_disable = 1
> ```

You might want to disable the indentation from the plug-in and use `'cindent'` or `'smartindent'` to give you basic indentation (such as indenting on opening curly braces and dedenting on closing curly braces.) Perhaps that would be less disruptive overall.